# Filepath setting in Xpages theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes, xpages, filepath

I added bootstrap files to a Lotus database using Java perspective in Lotus Domino Desinger.
I created theme for the application with resource references to the css, js and image files of the bootstrap framework.
In the browser the filepathes are replaced slashes:
`.js/jquery%2Fjquery-1.8.2.min.js&amp;bootstrap%2Fjs%2Fbootstrap.min.js`
instead of
`.js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
bootstrap/js/Fbootstrap.min.js`
What causes this and how to fix it?

Update:
slashes instead of backslashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a combined resource for all js and css files in a single file with this long name.

In case it doesn't work *switch* property "**Use runtime optimized JavaScript ans CSS resources**" in Application Properties at tab XPages *off*. Then every single resource will stay in its own file.

Comment: I mean slashes, the original description was wrong. So I used slashes, and got the same problem as described above.